# Why would a movie question not meet the standard on Movies/TV and be accepted on Scifi/Fantasy?

Tags: discussion

I attempted to post a [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/which-film-was-the-first-to-show-us-the-face-of-god) on Movies/TV and got the "Doesn't meet the standards" message. Then I posted it on Scifi/Fantasy, where it did meet the standards but got downvoted and migrated back to Movies/TV. What's up with that? I don't mind the downvote, but I'd like to learn from it.

Comment: Looks like SFF might have lower standards in asking questions if the quality filter isn't turned on here

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise [The quality filter is turned on here.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1550/how-can-i-delete-my-user-account-from-scifi-site-and-also-how-to-meet-the-quali)

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise - why don't you raise the standards by asking high quality questions instead of complaining about low quality in others'?

Comment: Because all of TV Tropes has been mined already @dvk

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise: Criticizing others continuously clearly has not had effect you seem to desire.  Perhaps you might want to consider leading by example?  You seem quite sure how to improve the site, yet you have avoided posting more than a few questions and answers.  If one is so sure of what the site needs, that insight should make it easy to be an exemplary participant as opposed to just saying, "This is wrong," without providing constructive criticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the shortness of a question is part of the quality filter.  I've gotten that error before myself, and usually take care of it by fleshing out the answer a bit with more detail or some introductory material.

Answer (score 2):

We have decided previously that we don't allow questions dealing with [modern religions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1056/98). Calling any modern religion fantasy is a state that we just don't want to be in. The question you asked could well fit into a general movie discussion, but it is not on topic here. I'm not familiar enough with what the movies site considers on topic, but if it was going to be on topic anywhere, it would be there. And I will give you there is a small chance that the movie could be featured in something that would be on topic here, but most likely, that is not the case.

Comment: I understand Movies/TV is a better fit, and that religon can be a slippery slope. I was actually hoping for it to be migrated over there. It was worth the downvote to get it where I meant it to be. I was just perplexed as to why one site filtered it out and why the other didn't. I didn't cut and paste, so perhaps I tweaked it when I entered it @ Scifi. Anyway, thanks for addressing my question.

Comment: So only modern religions?  No respect for that "ol' time religion?"