# Answers that count religious texts as fiction

Tags: discussion, answers

I understand that *questions* based on counting religious texts as fiction are off topic here. What about *answers* (such as [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126226/what-is-the-earliest-example-of-a-blighted-land-created-by-human-or-semi-human/126292#126292)) which count a religious text (in this case the Bible) as fiction? I suppose they are considered inappropriate, but what are we supposed to do when we see one? Can we flag a moderator to have it removed? Is "not an answer" the right reason for flagging, or is it "rude or abusive", or do we need a custom reason?

**Edit.** I posted this question **after** reading the old question which this allegedly duplicates. The old question concerned **questions** about religious texts, and it was decided that such questions could be closed as being off topic. I did not see anything there about **answers** that cite religious texts as fiction, and the remedy "vote to close as off topic" does not apply to answers.

Comment: @anaranjada The question isn't as clear as it could be, but how could it be on topic if it's *not* asking for fictional examples?

Comment: My take is that we should avoid trying to disqualify or remove answers unless they are genuinely offensive or terrible.  This is neither, in my opinion.  When in doubt, leave it alone and let people express their feelings via voting.

Comment: I think we should delete that answer immediately. It clearly and distinctly falls foul of our existing policy on '[religious works as fiction](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1053/20774)'

Comment: As to what your actions should be, a flag would be the most appropriate course of action to bring it to a Moderator's attention so that they can delete it.

Comment: @user14111 - The rule of thumb is "**Religious works aren't considered fictional**". It's pretty clear that this applies across the board, to both questions and answers, hence why I closed this as a dupe.

Comment: @Richard It's pretty clear "that religious works aren't considered fictional" applies to answers as well as questions. What's not quite so clear, and was clearly the point of my question, was what action should be taken. "Vote to close" does not apply to answers. Which leaves: downvote, flag as not-an-answer, flag as rude-or-offensive, flag-for-custom-reason, post a comment suggesting to the owner to delete the answer, ignore.

Comment: @user14111 - Given the potential for offense to be caused, flagging for a moderator (and or marking the answer to be deleted) seems the most appropriate course of action.

Comment: @user14111 - if an answer was based on a book that was clearly non-SFF, it would and should get flagged as "NAA". Same story with any offtopic material, religious included.

Comment: I'm at a loss why this has been re-opened. Are you expecting the result of this to be any different?

Comment: @Richard: OP is not asking whether it's allowed.  They are assuming it is not allowed and asking *what to do about it when it happens*.

Comment: The whole question of whether they should be treated as fiction is avoided when you consider the fact that this entire site is fiction/fantasy. But that makes me wonder... would a fan-fic about a religious text be considered off-limits?

Comment: @user14111 Maybe you should unaccept Richard's answer since it's no longer the highest-voted and thus no longer such a good reflector of community consensus?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - What's kinda weird is that my answer does still represent the concensus view (e.g. that they should be mod-flagged and deleted), and yet has still managed to get downvoted :-)

Comment: ASR's answer now has triple the score of Richard/Valorum's, so it appears to reflect community consensus whether it's accepted or not.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Interestingly, more people agree with my answer (21 vs 20), but more people also disagree with it (19 vs 3), despite the fact that it's semi-identical to AncientSwordRage's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paraphrasing Beofett's answer [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/should-we-exclude-religious-texts-and-which)

### Any *answer* which states (or even strongly implies) that a religious work is a work of fiction should be immediately flagged for moderator attention, pending deletion.

> *"I think that a ban on questions on religious works is appropriate. It
>   leaves us open to too much controversial debate, potentially offended
>   visitors, and the likelihood of duplicated content with other SE sites
>   (i.e. the ones dedicated towards those specific religions)."*

If you feel like you want to go further, you always have the option of downvoting and/or leaving a comment explaining our general policies.

Comment: On the other hand, when people simply ask for "the first story" for something, then I think it's fair game since even non-fiction accounts count as a story. We have precedence for it in our answers.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - It's never fair game to refer to someone's religious text as fictional. You can, of course, refer to it as being *inspirational* of a fictional work (for example, there are clear linkages between passages from the Bible and the ending of The Matrix).

Comment: Eh, I wasn't saying it was "fictional". But yeah, given we're on a site for science *fiction*, I suppose I could see where that could cause issues. Which makes me feel guilty that I scored a bunch of points for citing an Indian manuscript for the first story of time travel...

Comment: @fuzzyboots - Some early Indian works are quite readily accepted as being works of fiction (the Ramayana, for example), even though they contain references to gods and legends. You may also want to note that most religious works also contains  "meta-stories" and parables that are explicity considered as fictional.

Comment: This seems like kind of a crazy policy, but I guess it might be worth it to avoid some individuals being offended to the point of explosion. I mean, granted, for any particular religious work there are a lot of people who look at it as 'true' and therefore non-fiction, but for *any* religious work, the *majority* of people consider it a work of fiction.

Comment: @dcshannon - Yes, so by excluding all religious works, we're acting equably to everyone and no one gets pissed off that we called their holy book a work of fiction or fantasy.

Comment: "Harry Potter is my religion. In order to not offend me, all Harry Potter questions and answers should be removed!" How do you counteract this argument?

Comment: @oriol - I'd counter it by pointing out that it's not your religion.

Comment: It was an example. More precisely, how you can know if some book is considered religious by someone?

Comment: @oriol - You have to use common sense, something that is sadly (and ironically) not all that common.

Comment: @Oriol I agree that this seems open to interpretation, and I thought about how we treat things like "Jedi", which is becoming very popular as a declared religion, when I wrote the answer Richard linked. That's why I think the "book store test" is valid: if you could reasonably expect books on the topic to be found in most bookstore's "religion" section, then it is a religion.  This solves the "Harry Potter is my messiah" issue, as well as the Jedi issue. However, anyone claiming either of those two as their religion is either trolling, or likely not easily offended by discussion of the books.

Comment: @Beofett - Except that "Jedi" isn't a real religion. Its primary use in real life seems to be to act as a parodical construct to argue against real religions being granted rights, in much the same way that someone might call themselves a Pastafarian. Those very few individuals who seem to consider themselves genuine adherents, ironically state that their religion isn't actually based on the books and films, merely inspired by them.

Comment: @Richard that... would seem to very much validate what I just wrote, neh?  Most "Jedi" aren't serious about it, but some few might be. However, the fact that the books are generally classified as sci-fi in bookstores justifies us in saying "no" if someone says "I'm a sincere Jedi, and you treating star wars as fiction offends me!  Please remove all content that discusses star wars as fiction!"

Comment: @beofett - my contention is that serious Jedi (by their own admission) don't view the books as holy writ, nor do they contend that the books aren't fiction.

Comment: @Richard Again, see my previous comment: " However, anyone claiming either of those two as their religion is either trolling, or *likely not easily offended by discussion of the books.*". It seems an irrelevant point of pedantry, however.  Having a relatively objective guideline saves us from tedious arguments along the lines of "Jedi don't treat the books as holy writ" with the response of "yeah, well I'm a Jedi, and **I do** view the books as holy writ!".  Yes, the ever popular (and ever subjective) " common sense" rule covers that, but opens us to more argument.

Comment: @beofett - Ah, perhaps things would be easier if you just replaced "common sense" with "Richard says".

Comment: @Richard no thanks.   Not sure what you're trying to say with that, or if you're even serious, but I happen to agree it is common sense.  It is just my experience that when dealing with trolls (such as someone demanding that they're a Jedi, and therefore our rules demand that no star wars books are treated as fiction), using the phrase "common sense" gives them license to argue what is and is not "common".

Comment: @Beofett - As far as I am aware, the only modern religion which could genuinely come into conflict with scifi/fantasy fiction is scientology, where the progenitor explored some of the themes in fiction, that he would go on to put into books that he explicitly stated were historical.

Comment: @Richard why does it have to be a modern religion? I could imagine the correct answer to a question being The Epic of Gilgamesh, or some religious play by Euripedes. The fact that a religion is old doesn't make it any more or less offensive to the people who observe it. Classical Greek mythology will be in the fiction section of a book store even though it doesn't really belong there.

Comment: @Thoth19 - For the record, the Greek, Roman religions plays are fair game for being described as *religious myths*, largely because all of their followers died out centuries ago. The Epic of Gilgamesh, by comparison was written as a work of fiction.

Comment: @Richard That is false. Apparently Panagiotis Marinis still worships Zeus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenism_(religion)#Claims_of_continuity). The point you should be making is that these minorities are small enough that they likely won't cause a political controversy and if they do the negative utils will be small compared to the utils of the ease of utilizing SE for everyone else while offending them. Claiming that people don't exist is a poor mechanism because proving a negative is hard and there are many people.

Comment: @Thoth19 - That a single individual claims it, doesn't make it true. Is it more likely that his family are the sole heirs to the true religion of Greece (representing an unbroken chain of Hellenic worship that stretches back a thousand years) or that he was just told it by his parents and believes them? Also, the fact that a single individual has a non-standard religious belief doesn't give him the right to dictate SE policy on religions, any more than the occasional 7th Day Voldemortian would...

Comment: @Richard You make two points here. Only one of them is relevant. Your first point is false, as I pointed out, and your second is what I said above. Continuing to rehash this is pointless.

Comment: So someone's religion is only "real" as long as you deem it to be? Interesting. This whole policy is (a) absurdly contradictory (you're banning content that implies arbitrarily-selected religious texts to be fictional, but not ones that imply them not to be?), (b) exceedingly dangerous (only you get to choose whose religion is "real", as explored in comments above). Hum.

Comment: A religion must meet the common sense test. I'd argue that one of those criteria should be "*actual adherents*".

Comment: @DCShannon, for what it's worth, I do not consider *any* religious work to be fictional.  "Fact/fiction" is a dividing line that is far from an exhaustive categorization of types of thought.  For example, none of the following could be called either "fact" or "fiction": opinions, orders, suggestions, questions, speculations....  To label something as "nonfiction" does not imply in any way that its total content is "factual statements of fact."

Comment: @Wildcard - For what it's worth, I personally consider **all** religious works to be fictional. I'd still argue to the hilt that we should be respectful of other people's beliefs. The flipside is that I'd expect believers to be respectful of others too.

Comment: Trolls should be dealt with for what they are, trolls. Arbitrary rules about what is or not considered fiction are very bad, for many reasons, all of which have been touched upon here. There is either factual (actual history, with evidence), or fiction (everything else). Let's all be honest and say it for what it is, this rule was created specifically for Muslims and Christians, as no one else ever has the balls to try to say their religion is all fact and no fiction. Special rule for religious text == special status for religious people, and that is offensive to atheists.

Comment: @Oni - The story of Gilgamesh was almost certainly intended as *fiction for entertainment* whereas the bible is intended as fact.

Answer (score 26):

There're a few things to consider here:

### Offensive content should be flagged to the moderators.

If it's obviously offensive or you, yourself find it offensive then please flag it as such. This is the flag option to select:

[image: Rude or Abusive flag options]

Things I would flag as this is *explicitly* saying that a religion is fictional. Subtly implying it as such is not for instance offensive to me, but I would 100% accept a flag from someone saying they were offended by such implications. I'd much rather listen to the community speaking up about it than impose what I thought the community wanted.

### Non-fiction sources are simply poor answer fodder

The other side of the coin is that, answers that use a non-fiction source are simply poor answers in some case. First though, let's be clear on which meaning of fiction I'm referring to:

1. Literature in the form of prose, especially novels, that describes imaginary events and people.
   **synonyms**:   novels, stories, creative writing, imaginative writing, works of the imagination, prose literature, narration, story telling
2. something that is invented or untrue.
   "they were supposed to be keeping up the fiction that they were happily married"
   **synonyms**:   fabrication, invention, lies, fibs, concoction, untruth, falsehood, fantasy, fancy, illusion, sham, nonsense;

I would say the majority of religious texts may come under the category of *Stories*, or *Narration* implying they are *invented* or *untrue* is likely not the intention of the original author. The accepted answer on the related meta post uses the idea of whether it would be in the sci-fi or fantasy section of a book shop. While it's not an exhaustive criterion, it's probably easier than trying to understand the intention of the original author in some cases.

By either metric most answers that treat religious texts (regardless whether they're Judeo-Christian, Islamic, Hindu, Shinto, Buddhist, Druidic, Pagan, Ancient Roman, Ancient Greek etc....) are simply not providing a good answer, and I'd expect them to get the same response as using [Time Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Cube) as a scientific source on Physics.SE - it's just not on topic. Downvote and move on.

### Inspiration isn't implying fiction

There is one exception though. If a question is asking for the [inspiration](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspiration) behind a work of fiction, answers citing religious texts should be considered valid. That is, you can change the wording of:

> What's the earliest reference to *type of thing* (e.g. talking snakes, transmutation alchemy, angels with more than two wings) in science-fiction/fantasy?

Which is very broad, assuming that one thing or trope has a definite single earliest reference.

To be more clearly:

> What's the inspiration behind *definite example of thing* (e.g. Mrs. Plithiver in Legend of the Guardians, Philosopher's stone in Full Metal Alchemist, Evangelion).

Comment: Would you 100% accept it if I started flagging Harry Potter posts saying that Harry Potter is my religion and I am offended by it being treated as fiction? I hope not. What criteria would you use? I don't think common sense, [proposed by Richard](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9523/30638#comment26096_9535), is well-defined.

Comment: @oriol I'd 100% accept you were offended. I don't think there's an easily defined measure for what is,  or isn't offensive.

Comment: Fair enough. Then I just hope everybody will behave properly and won't flag all posts as offensive to their religion, unless it's really the case.

Comment: Hm. Sometimes a religious text contains something that *is* supposed to be fictional. For example, most of Jesus' parables are not to be taken literally (or at least most Christians I have ever heard address the subject believe that); they're just illustrations of a point. This is somewhat of an odd situation, since the telling is believed to be an actual event, but not the parable told. What about those? Are those forbidden as well just to avoid the risk? Or would it be acceptable if the answer made clear that the text itself gives strong indication that the story is fictional?

Comment: While I do mostly agree with your answer, I *highly* doubt that you’d delete all Harry Potter questions simply because one person had based a religion upon them, even if that person were entirely sincere. I wouldn’t, anyway.

Comment: @Adamant the fiction predates the religion though...

Comment: It just looked like you were implying that if someone were offended on the basis of their  religion (for whatever reason), you’d delete the offending content. I agree that it shouldn’t be deleted (and that that’s one of the reasons).

Comment: If asked for the earliest reference of some idea in fiction, and the earliest reference is actually in a religious text, pointing that out seems like a good answer that provides a useful account of the idea's history (although also including the first explicitly-fictional source is probably good). If some idea originated from real life, I'd think that could make for a useful answer even though it's obviously not fiction. The only reason I might agree with banning religious text in principle, is if the religious start misusing such answers to promote their religion.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I think it's on the question writer to make clear the distinction between *earliest reference to something in fiction* and *earliest reference in fiction to something*. I suspect the the former is likely off-topic, unless phrased as "What's the inspiration for *thing in fiction*" and then it's clear what the question is wanting.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Extending the religious-text-to-real-world analogy, if someone asks e.g. "what is the earliest reference in fiction to vampires", a good (if fictional) answer might be "the idea of vampires is actually believed to have originated from the real-world person, Nosferris Vambeuller, who used to drink blood, and they first appeared in fiction in the SuchAndSuch novel". Maybe the earlier real-world example is more of a footnote, or maybe it's useful enough to stand on it's own merits.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I think it's very much a footnote, see the section 'Non-fiction sources are simply poor answer fodder'.

Answer (score 10):

Treating religious texts as fiction is a surefire way to start wars. Let's not do that. Also, it does not adhere to the "be nice" policy of Stack Exchange.

**Answers that treat religious works as fiction should be flagged for moderator attention, to be deleted as soon as possible.**

However, [the example](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/126292/19561) used does not do that. It merely shows that the idea of blighted lands is much older than last century fiction.

As such, *that answer* should not have been deleted. Edited for clarity at most.

Comment: That question asked which work of fiction was the first. The person who answered then referred to the bible. You can certainly edit the hell out of the answer to make it less controversial, but that doesn't seem to be what the OP intended when they posted.

Comment: @Richard Would you leave the answer if the OP had already made it as uncontroversial as possible?

Comment: @Kevin - Personally I favour an absolutist approach. Religious works shouldn't be treated as fictional, period.

Comment: @richard I agree, but they can provide examples of tropes or ideas used in fiction _as well_.

Answer (score 3):

There have been a spate of 'Earliest example' questions.

I think these are on topic for the site, as it is interesting to see how speculative ideas have emerged and changed over time as society and science has changed.

However some ideas may also have roots in religious texts. I'm thinking of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/126313/1132) as an example. It is not commenting on the on the text in question, just mentioning that it contains an idea.

I think this is not going to be uncommon with such questions, many fantasy and scifi ideas may have roots in religious texts. They are some of the oldest texts that exist and they contain many fantastical ideas.

I also think it is perfectly valid as an answer and is not offensive unless a user explicitly cites it as fiction or untrue.

Comment: If the question is "*what is the first example of x **in any form of literature***", then the question is probably badly scoped. We're not Literature:SE, nor should we try to be. If the question is "*what is the first example of x **in fiction***", then we should avoid using religious texts as examples. Simple really.

Comment: @Richard - Note that the question being discussed does not specifically demand fictional examples.  It mentions some, but as its scope is understanding how representations change over time due to public consciousness, an older example that is likely to be well-known by a large number of people is a relevant factor, whether it's literal truth, complete fiction, or myth/legend (in the academic sense that doesn't attempt to distinguish whether true or false).

Comment: @Valorum, I agree with you, but *"what is the first example of this common science fiction trope to appear in any form of literature"* is not out of scope and could cite a religious text in an answer.  But preferably it would also include the earliest *sci-fi* example of the trope, as well as the religious literature that possibly gave inspiration.

Comment: @Wildcard - And that would be absolutely fine. As long as the question is about a **recognisably scifi (or fantasy) trope** then that's also on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Are stories from e.g. Gilgameš or Herakles considered as not religious?
If so how those different from stories of Jesus of Nazareth.

Comment: Because Gilgamesh was written *as fiction* (and meant to entertain) whereas the bible was written as an account of events and intended as a religious text.

Comment: @Valorum: Unfortunately, this is blurrier than you make it out to be. For example, Greek mythology was not written as fiction (at the time) but is widely treated as such today (see for example Disney's *Hercules*). Yet some people still believe in Zeus et al. today (though perhaps not very many people).

Comment: @Kevin - There are no extant Zeus worshippers. There are *revivalists* who claim to worship Zeus (and maybe they do) but I clump them into the same category as Church of the Jedi and other neo-religions.

Comment: @Valorum: Surely you're not using "is it Abrahamic?" as the criterion?

Answer (score -1):

I would say this a really basic problem with a basic solution.

**Story** itself means *a relation of events*, there is no implication that it must be true or fictional. So, when someone is asking for the first occurence of whatsoever, the bible or a Cicero's text or a fantasy book are all at the same level of dignity; saying that the Ramayana (for example) is not a story is against logic itself.

"**What has been the first work of fiction to**"...well, no need to offende someone by taking the Qur'an as an example.

---

Side note: unless there is a specific .se for literature (I didn't check, honestly), all the questions that try to figure the first reference to something (and/or the inspiration for something) in a neutral way should be really appreciated on SF&F as they gives people a way to better understand where the things they like come from.

Comment: You may have noticed that we're **only interested in fiction** on this site, not stories. There was a literature:SE but it died in Beta.

Comment: It [might be making a comeback](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature?referrer=pG-ejQRSCH0RMbN3ps5MrA2)! Still needs more people to commit to it though.

Answer (score -3):

Only if it's in an offensive way. There are hundreds of religions and some are blatantly jokes, some might be seen as a joke but are practised seriously, some are just dead-serious. A bunch of them are grey areas regarding seriousness. Not allowing for an answer to treat joke religions as fiction would result in a very silly answer.

I would flag for moderator attention, only if the answer is offensive. If the question is something like an identify this fictional story and someone suggests the Bible, that would be very offensive to Christians. But if the answer does nothing more or less than answer the question, and it treats religious texts as fiction it doesn't have to be offensive. Most Christians no longer believe the earth is 8000 years old, even though the Bible says so, there are parts of all great religions that are already widely regarded as fiction, why should we pretend we're stupid?

Comment: Pastafarianism may be recognised as a religion in some places, but even its most ardent adherent would be willing to admit that its purpose is to troll other religions. They don't *actually* believe, hence there is no scope for real offense.

Comment: @Richard Yes, that's my point, if there are religions like that, then where do we draw the line? We should determine offensiveness, if sufficiently offensive, flag it, otherwise leave it be.

Comment: @Richard I took Pastafarianism as an example because it shows that in some cases it would be very silly to flag, the story is clearly fiction. I can imagine there are less extreme cases, where lots of people think about it the same way as Pastafarianism, but it's followers actually take it seriously. What do you think does have a scope for real offense? Scientology, perhaps? I can honestly not grasp that there are people who believe in that crap, but the truth is, there are people who believe in it, should we pretend it's all real or should we exclude it entirely from our answers?

Comment: As I said in an earlier comment, Scientology is a bit of an 'edge-case' because some of Hubbard's writings are considered *historical* while others are overtly fictional but supposedly inspired by real (historical) events. The best thing to do is to treat all the bits that they say are religious texts as religious texts.

Comment: @Richard They claim that whole "alien-planet got too crowded so they shot some of their population into earth's volcanoes and that's where our negative emotions  come from" to be religious text, right? Because to me, that's in the same ballpark as a flying spaghetti monster. Yet a lot of people could get offended by claiming it's BS.

Comment: The problem is that while you, personally may find their religious stories absurd, **everyone's religion is absurd to someone else**.

Comment: @Richard Do you not understand me or? You said yourself "Pastafarianism may be recognised as a religion in some places, but even its most ardent adherent would be willing to admit that its purpose is to troll other religions." yet you keep advocating all religions should be treated with respect..... I'm asking **where** you think the line is, because apparently there **is** a line.

Comment: The line is that to enjoy the protection of our policy, a religion needs to be an actual religion, not a parody or the bizarre ramblings of a single individual based on their misreading of a clearly fictional work

Comment: Although the original Starwars is widely known to be a cinematic trilogy, one has to wonder where George Lucas got the inspiration to write such a story. Personally, I believe it was given to him as a divine message from the God of the Galaxy. Although I agree that actors and actresses did portray the events in Starwars, the events themselves really happened, and I will be flagging all posts that refer to those events as merely fiction because they deeply upset me. Note that i'm not joking here. I truly believe these events happened and it does form part of my religious teachings as a Jedi.

Comment: FWIW, there is a [court ruling about pastafarianism](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2016/04/pastafarianism-is-satire-and-not-protected-religion-court-rules/).

Comment: @wildcard [mean while in Europe](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-14135523).