# Are the sci-fi like parts of the Bible on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I hope this question doesn't offend anyone, but here goes:
Are the sci-fi like parts of the Bible (Ezekiel's vison - Ezekiel 1:1–3:27 etc) considered on topic?

Comment: [How do we differentiate between religion and fiction](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10186/how-do-we-differentiate-between-religion-and-fiction) is also relevant

Answer (score 3):

I think part of the problem is that, by claiming parts of it are "sci-fi", you are essentially saying "this is fictional". It would be a bit like asking if we can talk about the parts of Egyptian history that are "sci-fi like" like the pyramids.

That said, as Valorum commented in [How do we differentiate between religion and fiction?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10186/how-do-we-differentiate-between-religion-and-fiction), we really need to take things on a case-by-case basis. What sort of questions were you thinking of asking?

Comment: I'm an Orthodox Jew. I actually believe it is 100% true. However, it still doesn't mean there aren't parts which are sci-fi like.

Comment: @TheAsh if they're not fictional, they're not on topic. So either you're calling it fiction and it's a debatable question, or you view it as fact althought "tending towards science fiction" and then it's off-topic.

Comment: @TheAsh - I would note that questions about the mythological nature of the Bible are on-topic on [Mythology](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/), and of course questions about Judaism (including, probably, the Bible from a Jewish perspective) are on-topic on [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is a good case of the "Nonfiction doesn't become fiction by being false" rule.