# Are apocryphal religious texts fair game?

Tags: discussion

I was reading [When where the first links between Cain and vampirism made in literature?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225513/when-where-the-first-links-between-cain-and-vampirism-made-in-literature), where [an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/272498/23243) stated that versions of Genesis before the 1800s included an additional line alluding to the vampirism, and it got me to thinking that, with all of the apocryphal texts out there, I wouldn't be surprised if there was one that matches. I came upon an apocryphal text from about 100 AD, *Life of Adam and Eve*, which has Cain drinking Abel's blood, referenced [here](https://sites.nd.edu/manuscript-studies/2015/04/09/the-slaying-of-abel-in-apocryphal-tradition/), but I'm not certain if including a religious text that's not considered canon (and is pretty obscure) is OK or not.

Comment: This feels like a duplicate: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9523/answers-that-count-religious-texts-as-fiction?rq=1 - "*There is one exception though. If a question is asking for the inspiration behind a work of fiction, answers citing religious texts should be considered valid.*"

Comment: That answer was completely wrong though. No such versions of Genesis exist. The answer was deleted after the author failed to provide any reference.