# How will the upcoming Noah film be handled?

Tags: discussion

The upcoming [Noah film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noah_%28film%29) is being produced in a style that feels like an epic fantasy movie just like LOTR or others.  Based on what I've read and seen it is not trying to be utterly faithful to the Biblical account, and so even if you believed this was really a true story you could see this as a fantasy take on the story.

We've already decided that general Bible based discussion is off topic here (see [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/why-was-this-question-about-the-old-testament-closed-as-off-topic) and [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/should-we-exclude-religious-texts-and-which)).  Will questions about the film be allowed and if so, how can we explain that?

Comment: What really bakes my noodle is, do we consider "Jesus Christ Superstar" ontopic?

Comment: @DVK - I love the people who use SE sites!

Comment: "Who is more powerful: Noah or 2 Elephants?"

Comment: The Bible itself may be off-topic, but that film would be an entirely different work. A better question would be whether or not Heston's Ten Commandments is on topic or not. Wikipedia calls it a religious historical epic, which is not a supported genre here. I would say the same of Noah.

Comment: There is always [movies.se]. It's still in beta but this would certainly be on-topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The movie is starring Odin, Van Helsing, Hrothgar, and Hermione Granger. We MUST make it on-topic.

On a more serious note, I think the general Meta consensus is that if the writer INTENDS the story to be fiction (e.g., the story of Christ in "Master and Margarita" by Bulgakov; or Marvel's Asgardians); it's SFF. If it's merely a movie about a religious event ("Passion of Christ" by Mel Gibson; or hell, Charlton Heston's "Ten Commandments") it's not.

Based on Wiki info, it seems to be the former. E.g.

> In October 2012, Emma Watson commented on the setting of the film: "I think what Darren's going for is a sense that it could be set in any time. It could be set sort of like a thousand years in the future or a thousand years in the past. [...] You shouldn't be able to place it too much."[20]

In other words, the events described in the Bible are merely used as an excuse to tell a dramatic story that Aronofsky wants to tell, set in an special setting.

That should make the movie on-topic in general.

**CAVEAT**: Questions that ask about movie events **based on discrepancies between the movies and Bible**, or **questions whose answer is expected to be based on Bible text or Biblical scholarship** (as opposed to movie script) should probably be offtopic.

Comment: To play Devil's advocate, no pun intended: "Producer Scott Franklin told Entertainment Weekly, "Noah is a very short section of the Bible with a lot of gaps, so we definitely had to take some creative expression in it. But I think we stayed very true to the story and didn't really deviate from the Bible, despite the six-armed angels." That seems to put the movie more towards "Ten Commandments" territory. BUT IT HAS Odin!

Comment: I would agree with your answer, but I guess we'll really just have to wait until it comes out to see. *BUT* in general, if the question is posed about the film `what did X result in` or `what powers did Y demonstrate in this battle`, then those should be on-topic, so long as answers will not clearly end up as citing scripture