# Is it time for Ragnarök for the [norse-gods]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burnination

We have a firm consensus that religion ([Should we exclude religious texts, and which?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1053/70236)) and mythology ([Should myths be considered religions?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6838/70236)) by itself is off-topic here, and that calling religious works fiction is not okay ([What's the best way to respectfully discuss stories which fictionalize religious subjects?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10949/70236)).

Despite that we still have the [religion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion), [mythology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology), and [norse-gods](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norse-gods) tags.

The first two deserve their own discussion as they too seem to be used inconsistently, but this post is about [norse-gods](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norse-gods) - do we need this tag?

11 questions currently have this tag. [One of them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54836/at-what-point-are-asgardians-considered-full-grown) is only about mythology, and not SFF, and should be closed; 3 [are [story-identification] questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norse-gods+story-identification); assorted others include Marvel Cinematic Universe questions; a Tolkien/ASOIAF question, and so forth.

Should this tag remain, or should we initiate a burnination?

Comment: Don't see a reason for downvoting this as it's worth discussing this topic as it extend ms to various other tags.

Comment: I mean, the title alone deserves a +1, and I think it's important to address.

Comment: @Edlothiad thats not always how votes on meta work. An upvote may mean "Yes, do this" and a downvote may mean "No do not do this" even on the question. It is confusing I know....

Comment: @Skooba that's not how it works, I was told a vote on a question is whether it's worthy of discussion. The answers are for policies. Questions are meaningless as policy decisions

Comment: I feel like time is better spent focusing on improving existing or creating new tags. I'm really tired of these burninate suggestions over and over again. There are alternatives, but the onus is on the answer to counter the "burn it" suggestion. None of these questions are ever "What's the best thing we can do about this tag?" it's always just "Can we destroy it?" Seems lazy and destructive, and in recent history the answer has generally been "No" followed by a list of similar reasons.

Answer (score 10):

### This tag is being used entirely correctly and should remain.

There are presently 11 uses of this tag. Excluding those closed for other reasons, almost all of them are asking about ***the Norse Pantheon in relation to a science fictional setting***.

[Short story collection about ancient gods in modern times](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153850/short-story-collection-about-ancient-gods-in-modern-times) - Norse gods in modern times.
[Book with Norse gods and runes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146076/book-with-norse-gods-and-runes) - Book set in fantasy world where Norse Gods are a thing
[When was Thor first portrayed as an advanced alien, not a god?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94147/when-was-thor-first-portrayed-as-an-advanced-alien-not-a-god) - Question about whether the Asgardians are aliens rather than literal gods
[Did Gaiman make up "Loki Skywalker", or does he have a source for it?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75580/did-gaiman-make-up-loki-skywalker-or-does-he-have-a-source-for-it)  - Question about the Norse Gods in relation to Star Wars
[How did humans know about Thor and Loki?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54851/how-did-humans-know-about-thor-and-loki) - Question about the Norse Pantheon on Earth-616.
[Short story including aliens who are identified with Loki and Thor (from anthology c. 1970)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34268/short-story-including-aliens-who-are-identified-with-loki-and-thor-from-antholo) - Question about aliens who may have provided the inspiration for the Norse Gods.

etc etc.

Comment: But do we need this tag? Should we then create tags for any future pantheons?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Yes, we need tags that help people find things that they're interested in. That is the very purpose of tags and their reason for existing.

Comment: But Norse gods aren't on-topic here; they may be featured in some works of fiction, but that's not grounds enough to have a tag for them.

Comment: Questions about the Norse Pantheon aren't on-topic. Questions about the Norse Pantheon *in relation to science fiction* are perfectly well on topic and worthy of a tag

Comment: *And*, importantly, questions about the Norse pantheon in relation to sci-fi/fantasy may well be answerable by experts in the Norse pantheon itself, who'd like to be able to find a list of such questions using the tag system.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Story identification isn't on-topic here either. We close story identification questions when they're not about sci-fi or fantasy works.  What should we do about the [tag:story-identification] tag?

Comment: @Randal'Thor That is the strongest argument for keeping the tag. Pity, I'd almost vote to burninate simply because the *Ragnarök of Norse Gods* could be a very funny and ironic event.

Comment: Since your answer was positively received, what do you think the usage guidance for the tag should be? The current excerpt is a definition, not a guidance.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Perhaps append something like "*within the constraints of a fictional universes such as Marvel and DC Comics"*

Comment: @Valorum Putting specific examples, especially from such popular franchises, might just make people think the *only* on-topic Norse gods are the ones from those particular franchises. Anyway, don't we already have a [tag:thor-marvel] tag, or something along those lines?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Perhaps something even more apparent like "*for example, those seen in x and y"*

Comment: @Rand Nope. The default `thor` is about Marvel's. We renamed it because that Thor is by far and away our most popular Thor for questions. We have `thor-mythology` for when it's about the Norse god.

Comment: How about `For questions about modern, fictional representations of traditional Norse gods, or how a work relates to Norse mythology.`?

Comment: @CreationEdge Ugh. Screw that. Thor is a Norse god with a >1000 year history, not a character in some random piece of 21st-century popular culture that'll soon be forgotten.

Comment: @Randal'Thor We had this discussion at some length during the big retagging effort, and _you specifically_ acquiesced because Marvel's Thor is the most important to _this stack_, and the `thor-mythology` is a rarely used tag, not as important to our stack.

Comment: @CreationEdge I don't remember all of that conversation, but I can't imagine myself agreeing that a tag called simply [tag:thor] should refer to a character from some recent pop-culture thing rather than what the name has meant for thousands of years. At the very least call it [tag:marvel-thor] (like we do for e.g. [tag:star-trek-data]).

Comment: @Randal'Thor https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35993654#35993654 Looks like you settled on `thor` with a "Bah." but we both agreed it should be renamed to `thor-marvel` and then we have no plain `thor`, but that was a step you needed to do. I'm still for `thor-marvel`, but also the default of actual usage being preferred if a mod doesn't do the rename.

Comment: @CreationEdge OK, thanks for finding the transcript. Right now I need to go and catch a train, but I'll rename the tag when I have the time, or you can flag for another mod to do it. The only thing we didn't seem to settle (and probably the reason why I didn't rename it there and then) is: should it be [tag:thor-marvel] or [tag:marvel-thor]? I said [marvel-thor] by analogy with [star-trek-data], but you seemed to be in favour of [thor-marvel].

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well, we went thor-mythology already so makes sense to do thor-marvel to match.

Comment: @CreationEdge OK, I changed [thor] to [tag:thor-marvel], and fixed the tag wiki excerpts for both that and [tag:thor-mythology]. Still debating whether to change the latter to simply [thor] ...